# Generating migrations script in Azure Agent is very very slow

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a project which is using EF `v5.0.7` with `netcore3.1` in ASP.NET web app.

```
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
         .....
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.7" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.7" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.7">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.7">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
```

I wrote a release steps in Azure Pipeline like the following:

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool: 
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

variables:
- name: projects
  value: **/MyProject.WebAPI.csproj
      
- name: buildConfiguration
  value: 'Release'
- name: privateFeed
  value: 'xxxxxxxx'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2 
  displayName: ".NET Core 3.1.x"
  inputs:
    version: '3.1.x'
    packageType: sdk

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Restoring Packages'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '$(projects)'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '$(privateFeed)'
    noCache: true
    
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '$(projects)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --no-restore'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Install EF Tools'
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'tool'
    arguments: 'install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.0.0'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
   displayName: 'Generate Regulator Validations Migration Script'
   inputs:
     command: 'custom'
     custom: 'ef'
     arguments: 'migrations script -o "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/RegVal.Migrations.sql" -i -c ApplicationDbContext -v --no-build  --configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
     workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/src/MyProject.WebAPI'
```

It's taking so much time to do the script generation, about 15m, but locally it's very fast.

I know my project targets 3.1 and the EF tools are 3.0 but the EF packages are 5, this didn't affect other projects to generate the scripts very quickly, and I even tried to use EF tools 5.0, still the same.

On my machine I have the following sdks installed (3, 5, 6), I prepared a docker machine using the same windows version I used as my agent's OS, I installed these three sdks version, tried to do the generation there, it's the same, very slow.

I don't know what I maybe missing here..

P.S:
The project originally was targeting .net core 7, then my colleague revert it back to 3, so maybe this is the reason? maybe something was not changed during the revert ?